# How to get text box value on keyboard enter key event in meteor JS?

Tags: meteor

**MY CODE**

```js
    Template.profile.events({
        'keypress .add_comment': function (evt, template){
            
            if(evt.which === 13){
                
                alert($(event.currentTarget).val());
            }
        }
```

my code is not working. please help me.

Thanks

Comment: i use above code and it is not working. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

The error is in your alert line. You need not access the event using $ in meteor.

I tried the following, and it worked beautifully.

```
  'keypress .add_comment': function (evt, template){

        console.log(evt);
        if(evt.which === 13){
          alert("Enter!");
        }
```

I'm not sure what you are trying to do, but do go through Meteor's tutorial. It's a bit different from the jQuery way of things. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use jquery for getting the text like

```
$('.add_comment').val();
```

or

```
$(evt.currentTarget).val();
```

You wrote the event instead of evt.